# Are there cases when the f-string is not better than older string formatting methods?

Tags: python, string-formatting, f-string

I personally couldn't think of anything, but I'm wondering if there are some edge cases, where an older method might be somehow better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69796852/2318649

Comment: If the string you want to format is a variable, f-strings aren't even an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often better to do logging calls via

```
log.info("some log {} data {} to be logged", arg1, arg2)
# will be `message.format(*args)` at the end of the day
```

vs.

```
log.info(f"some log {arg1} data {arg2} to be logged")
```

The reason is that if my logger is not configured to log INFO logs then the the second snippet does a potentially expensive string interpolation, converts the arguments to strings, etc. The first snippet does not do the interpolation and returns early without serializing the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you need to reuse the same template string in multiple ways is better to use formatted strings. For example take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69772410/create-a-msg-variable-to-use-instead-of-repeating-multiline-strings/69772518#69772518)

Answer (score 2):

f-strings aren't an option for anything you want to be localizable. An f-string is hard-coded directly into your program's source code, so you can't dynamically swap it out for a translated template string based on the user's language settings.